# Fill column with conditioned string from another column

Tags: mysql

I want to populate a column (Column2) on a table with a specific string conditioned from another column (Column1) in the same table, to have a result like so:

```
Column1                      | Column2
-----------------------------------------
potato.food                  | Potato
green_beans.food             | Beans
hard_boiled-egg.food         | Boiled Egg
chicken-nugget_sandwich.food | Sandwich
```

So basically anything that comes after the first "_" and before ".", and also (but not as important) substitute "-" with " " and capitalize the first letter in words.

I know it's a tall order, so thanks!

Comment: why don't you do it in your processing application? to use the substring in another query?

Comment: Yes I don't see the point of doing in mysql. Use php, perl, python ... instead.

Comment: `Mysql` or `Sql server` ? Both are very different database engines

Comment: My bad, i really don't have much experience in this, i guess it's MySQL and not SQL, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `SQL SERVER`

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) ='potato.food'

SELECT Substring(@str, Charindex('_', @str) + 1, Charindex('.', @str) - Charindex('_', @str) - 1)
```

This can be easily converted to `Mysql`

- `SUBSTRING()` - [SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)/[SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)
- `CHARINDEX()` - [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

Something like

```
SELECT Substring(Column1, Instr(Column1, '_') + 1, Instr(Column1, '.') - Instr(Column1, '_') - 1)
FROM   Yourtable
```

Comment: Yes! that worked! now all i need to do is substitute the column with the query result, thank you so much!